# Refazer array com um limite maximo de posições

Tags: php, laravel

Estou trabalhando com Laravel e estava olhando um template bootstrap para personalizar a aplicação e me deparei com este formato de exibir os *followers*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é como poderia tratar o array que trás meus usuários apenas com a foto e caso o array seja maior que 3 como no exemplo trazer a contagem dos demais usuários.

**Edit:**

```
$network_users = User::select('photo')->where('parent', Auth::user()->id)->get()->toArray();

$network_images = array();
foreach ($network_users as $user) {
    if (count($network_users) >= 4) {
        $count = count($network_users) - 4;
        array_push($network_images, $user);
    } else {
        $count = count($network_users);
        array_push($network_images, $user);
    }
}
$data = array(
    'count' => $count,
    'network_images' => $network_images
);
dd($data);
```

Montei nesse formato seguido a ideia de utilizar o *count*, essa seria a forma mais correta de trazer os dados ou teria alguma forma melhor?

Comment: Utilize o método count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar a matemática, veja:

Suponha que você tenha uma lista com 15 usuários e você mostrou 3 deles. O restante de usuários pode ser obtido através da subtração de `15` (o comprimento total da lista) e `3` (o número de usuários mostrados por padrão).

Você pode fazer isso de modo bastante simples, utilizando a função [`count`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php) para determinar o comprimento da lista.

Algo assim:

```php
<?php

// [...]

$usuarios_restantes = count($lista_de_usuarios) - 3;

// [...]
```